# GitLab Python module - Get commits from repository with specific revision

Tags: python, api, gitlab

I'm trying to get specific commits from revision period and specific branch from a list of repository like a `from <repository_name1> !old_rev! - <commits between> - !new_rev!` (it's just example) by using gitlab python module.

In previous I took commits from single repository with `git log origin/develop --format=format:"%ct_%h %s" --no-merges` and now I need the same output, but from python module.

`1671534303_18c67f3fa46 TASK-1137 TITLE` - example (it's important)

```
import gitlab

gl = gitlab.Gitlab(url="https://gitlab.domain.com", private_token="token")

projects_list = ['23', '218', '239', '246', '245', '265']
single_branch = "develop"

def get_projects():
    return [gl.projects.get(project_id) for project_id in projects_list]

def main():
    for project in get_projects():
        gitlab_commits = project.commits.list(ref_name=single_branch, get_all=True)
        print(gitlab_commits)

main()
```

How I can do that with gitlab python module?